# Node.js function metadata for code completion

Tags: javascript, webstorm, code-completion

So, the core of my problem is that I might not know what the thing I want is called. I think it's called "metadata", but Google doesn't turn up anything.
Anyway when you type a function's name in WebStorm (though I can not imagine this being unique to it) it will sometimes display a tooltip, telling you what the function does and what parameters it takes- this really cuts down the time needed to look stuff up. So, I want to bundle those with the functions I write. How do I do that, or at least what is it properly called?

Comment: [Is it done via JSDoc comments?](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/creating-jsdoc-comments.html)

Comment: It's called [code completion](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/editor-code-completion.html). See http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/configuring-javascript-libraries.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't one term for it, unfortunately. Microsoft's term is "IntelliSense." Various other terms are listed in [this answer on programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93201/what-is-the-term-for-intellisense-in-a-non-microsoft-world):

- Auto Code Completion
- Code Completion
- Code Hinting
- Code Assist

I believe the term they use at JetBrains (the people behind WebStorm and IntelliJ and such) is "Code Completion," based on [the WebStorm help](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/editor-code-completion.html).

More about WebStorm code completion [on their blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/). It looks like they'll work from the source code, using JSDoc if they find it.